# My wifi stopped working at all on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

HELP HELP ---  I've tryed everything that was suggested but nothing had any effect, so I still need someone to help fix this problem! I doubt that this is the only instance of this happening but in searching the existing questions haven't found a fix!
Thanks in advance!
HELP. I lost the wifi some time in Dec. 2016 (after a routine update) on our Thinkpad T61 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with the Intel Pro 4965 installed. The system was working fine up to that point and now the wireless network is not highlighted on the network screen (wired ethernet is working fine) and therefore no wireless networks are available. It's not a problem with the Intel adapter, as if I boot the system from an old CD (show and tell mode) the wifi works fine.
I'm a newby to linux and don't know many terminal commands but, in searching the internet about this problem, have executed some of those commands that were requested in some of those postings. They follow:

```
lshw
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 61
                serial: 00:1f:3b:04:2a:89
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl4965 driverversion=3.13.0-93-generic firmware=228.61.2.24 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:50 memory:df2fe000-df2fffff


dmesg
[   17.385816] iwl4965: Intel(R) Wireless WiFi 4965 driver for Linux, in-tree:
[   17.385820] iwl4965: Copyright(c) 2003-2011 Intel Corporation
[   17.385869] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[   17.386046] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link 4965AGN, REV=0x4
[   17.429578] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: device EEPROM VER=0x36, CALIB=0x5
[   17.430150] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: Tunable channels: 11 802.11bg, 13 802.11a channels
[   17.430252] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
[   17.873742] iwl4965 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 228.61.2.24
[   18.124091] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-4965-rs'


mel@mel-ThinkPad-T61:~$ iw dev
phy#0
    Interface wlan0
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr 00:1f:3b:04:2a:89
        type managed


mel@mel-ThinkPad-T61:~$ iwconfig
wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=14 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off          
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.



mel@mel-ThinkPad-T61:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1049] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Lenovo ThinkPad T61/R61 [17aa:20b9]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection [8086:4230] (rev 61)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Lenovo ThinkPad T51 [8086:1110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwl4965
```

Any help in solving this problem would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance.
Mel

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `cat /etc/lsb-release` terminal command.

Comment: Here goes:    mel@mel-ThinkPad-T61:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"

Answer (score 3):

You have a wrong kernel installed for Ubuntu 16.04. Connect to the internet by wire and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic
```

and reboot.

Comment: Sorry that had no effect on the problem :=(

Answer (score 0):

That happened to me once with 16.04. I solved using nmcli on the terminal.

```
nmcli con up id <network_name>
```

If you authenticated to this network prevously, that command should do the job.

Comment: I don't understand, what network name?

Comment: The one you want to connect to.... for example... Mels_Wifi...

Comment: No joy here is the command and response:

Comment: OOPS, mel@mel-ThinkPad-T61:~$ nmcli con up id Gatekeeper
Error: Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection.

Comment: @MelStimmel Did you find solution for your problem ? I think I have the same problem